# Installing third-party Python Packages to Work With ArcPy and ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, python, installation, arcgis-pro

My employer does not grant me permissions to use Python package managers like pip or conda since the websites that host these data are blocked.  In ArcMap 10.x I have been able to install third-party python packages (like simpkml, easygui, pyexiv2,or PIL) by downloading the files, use 7-Zip to crack into the files, and locate the Setup.py file.  Once I locate the Setup.py file I can open a command window in that location, tell Windows to use `path=%path%;C:\Python\27\ArcGIS10.5`  then `Python Setup.py install` to install the package. Then I am free to write code that imports arcpy as well as other libraries without fuss.

This trick does not work with the ArcGIS Pro version of Python 3 since the Python.exe file and the ArcPy library are stored in a locked directory with read only permissions.

[Using this information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm) I have created a second Python environment to install third-party packages but there is no Python.exe file in this newly created environment so again, my trick fails to install.

I understand that I can use the ArcGIS Pro Python Package Manager to install some packages but the ones I want to install on not in ESRI list of packages.

How do I install third-party packages so that I can use them in the same version of Python that stores ArcPy?

Comment: Is the `conda` command available from your command line? If I understand the documentation correctly a second conda environment is created in your user directory in which you would have write permissions. You would be able to use `conda activate` to activate that environment and then perform `pip install setup.py` to install a package from source.

Comment: @Kersten. I can create a new Python environment in my roaming Citrix profile at C:\Users\geraldg\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\gPython.  Opening a command window in this location and typing conda activate returned 'conda' is not a recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.